# SQL query for selecting houses that have no black furniture?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables in a SQL database:

```
house(id,Name), 
furniture(id,Name,Color) 
house_furniture(id,HouseID,FurnitureID).
```

How can i construct a query to get all house names that have no black tables without using sub queries?

Comment: Why do you believe you need to do with this without sub-queries? That is the most obvious solution.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I use SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this, this is for `sql-server` as you didn't tag anything

```
select h.Name
from house_furniture hf 
join house h on hf.HouseId = h.id
left join furniture f on hf.FurnitureID = f.id 
                     and f.Color = 'Black'
                     and f.Name = 'Table'
where f.Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This query works for MySQL 5.7 -

```
SELECT h.NAME
FROM house h
    ,furniture f
    ,house_furniture hf
WHERE hf.HouseID = h.id
    AND hf.FurnitureID = f.id
    AND f.NAME = 'tables'
    AND f.colour != 'black ;'
```